# Restrict to UITextField cursor should only focus on end of text

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextfield

I need to restrict to UITextField text cursor should only focus on end of text every time. Ex- if user entered OTP in textField and again he want to replace digit from text field when he tap to UITextField then cursor should focus on end of text only not beginning of text. I added below code

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField){

    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        let position = textField.endOfDocument
        textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: position, to: position)
    }
}
```

It is working On first time textfield selection. After once cursor focussed in UITextField that time it is moving to Start position if user tap on start position.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job...

Subclass `UITextField` and override `closestPosition(to point: CGPoint)`, always returning the end of the text:

```
class EndOnlyTextField: UITextField {
    override func closestPosition(to point: CGPoint) -> UITextPosition? {
        let beginning = self.beginningOfDocument
        let end = self.position(from: beginning, offset: self.text?.count ?? 0)
        return end
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let customTextField = EndOnlyTextField()
        
        customTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(customTextField)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            customTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            customTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            customTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
        // so we can see the text field
        customTextField.borderStyle = .roundedRect

    }
    
    // tap anywhere outside the text field to end editing
    //  to make it easy to test
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
}
```